# Decoding Unknown MIDI Events

Tags: java, events, parsing, midi

I'm writing a MIDI file reader in Java (mostly as an exercise, possibly for use in an Android project as it doesn't include the javax.sound.midi library). I'm following [this](http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html) specification.

I have the specification details implemented nicely in my project, with the actual reading progressing on an event-by-event basis. An `InputStream` is opened on the file, and that same object is passed around to parse various event objects in such a way that when an event is done parsing itself, the stream is positioned at the next event. This is all working splendidly.

My first test file is simply a tempo map with an empty data track created in Sonar 8. The tempo track is parsed perfectly. The empty track has the following data after its chunk identifier and track name:

`00 B0 07 47 00 0A 40 00 FF 2F 00`

The first bytes are successfully parsed. `00` = delta time of 0, `B0` = Controller Event on channel 0, `07` = Main volume control, `47` = volume value of 71.

The next bytes are confusing me. `00 0A 40` The most likely case is that it's a Pan event with value 64. `0A` is a type of Controller event, which I expect to be preceded by `B0` as is the volume event. But since it's not preceded by a known event identifier byte, my reader fails to parse this event.

So I guess my question is how can account for this type of event? Is it acceptable in the file format to string Controller events together like this with a single `B0` identifier? Additionally, if I encounter unidentifiable event types in a file, is there really a way to know how much data I can skip if I don't know what the event is supposed to be? I'd like to be able to skip unknown events so my reader won't fail, but if I can't identify the event I'm not sure how to skip it. Would love some insight on these specific cases.

Comment: I've gained some insight from looking at a non-empty data track (a track with actual notes). While I expected a bunch of Note-On events (0x9), I see one Note-On event followed by all the notes in the track. Also interesting is that there are no Note-Off events, there are Note-On events with velocity 0 where the note should end. So I've come to believe that an event identifier not only identifies the next event, but that all bytes following the event identifier as events of that type until another event identifier is found. I would still appreciate confirmation or further explanation on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [midi file parsing, unrecognised event type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719366/midi-file-parsing-unrecognised-event-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is called running status. It's part of the MIDI specification. What you are doing is exactly the right thing. Sorry you had to figure it out by reverse engineering a MIDI data stream. [Here is a longer explanation of running status.](https://web.archive.org/web/20130305092440/http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/midispec/run.htm)

And, yes, a Note On event with velocity 0 is a Note Off. An actual Note Off event has an associated velocity, but almost no devices implement Note Off velocity, so it's much more common to see Note On with zero velocity.

Comment: That is a much more fleshed out specification, that's great. Many thanks, sir.

Comment: You're very welcome. I did a lot of MIDI-related programming back in the dawn of MIDI, so post any questions you may come across.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question in case anybody comes across this with a similar problem. (However unlikely that may be)

My above comment seems to hold. After reading the first identified event, if the subsequent event has no event identifier, it can be treated as the same type of event as the previous.

So in my example:

`00 B0 07 47 00 0A 40 00 FF 2F 00`

can be interpreted as two consecutive Controller events even though only one event identifier exists. So this is indeed a Volume event `07` followed by a Pan event `0A`, followed of course by the End of Track event `FF 2F 00`.

The solution in my code is to remember the last identifier that was seen, and if the next byte in the stream is not a valid identifier, the next chunk of bytes is interpreted as the same type of event as the previous event. Seems to make sense, and more importantly, my reader completes successfully.